# Linq namespace with RazorEngine

Tags: c#, linq, razorengine

I'm trying to use `LINQ` extension methods to query some **strongly** typed collections in a razor view, powered by RazorEngine. The problem is, it doesn't recognize `System.Linq` namespace; `@using System.Linq` generates an error in Intellisense:

> the type or namespace Linq does not exist in the namespace (are you
>   missing an assembly reference )

I'm looking for a solution without installing `WebPages` or `MVC`  packages.

---

Things I have already tried (from other answers for related problems around here):

- Moving RazorEngine.dll to bin
- Adding `<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />` to app.config
- Adding `<system.web><compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" /></system.web>` to app.config

Each of these measure solved some problems: initially Intellisense didn't work at all, now it recognizes the following `System` sub-namespaces:

> CodeDom, Collections, ComponentModel, Configuration, Data,
>   Deployment, Diagnostics, Drawning, EnterpriseServices, Globalization, 
>   IO, Media, Net, Reflection, Resourcers, Runtime, Security, Text,
>   Threading, Timers, Web, Windows, Xml

---

Snippet of my view:

```
@using RazorEngine.Template
@using System.Linq <!--namespace doesn't exist in System-->
@using Namespace.Of.My.Models
@inherits TemplateBase<ThisPageModel>

<table class="my-table-class">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Children)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>                    
                    @item.ListOfThings.First() <!--List<Things> does not contains a definition for First-->                     
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post the code from your view.  I have strongly typed views that use Linq with no problem, so would need to see your code to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @codeMonkey addded a snippet!

Comment: Thank you!  Well, I'm using MVC, so maybe that's the difference.  Have you checked out [this link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications)?

Comment: Make sure the build directory for the project is just bin/ (not the default bin/debug/) and copy the system.core.dll to the bin directory.

Comment: @codeMonkey Thanks! I assume using MVC include the necessary packages for VS to recognize the commands? Apparently, adding MVC to the project solves the problem, but I was looking for a way to the this without bloating the solution.

Comment: @DaveM Copying the system.core.dll to bin solved the problem even without changing the build directory (any idea why?). Could post this as an answer  so I can accept it?

Comment: @manoftheyear Done. I have no idea why. A visual studio dev would probably have to say. Using razor outside MVC doesn’t seem to be a common use case unfortunately. So support for that scenario in VS is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply copy `system.core.dll` to the bin directory of your project.

In the past I have also found it necessary to use `bin` as my build directory instead of `bin\debug` but this appears to no longer be necessary.